# How to find the value of the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate (analytically) the following integral ?
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$

Comment: $$
\int_{-1}^1 \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}(\arctan x)\\
\implies \arctan x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}|^1_{-1}-\int_{-1}^1 \! \arctan x \, \mathrm{d}(\arcsin x)
$$Perhaps I have just complexified the problem - I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x = \sin(u)$, then $v = \tan(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x = \sin\theta$. Then $dx = \cos\theta\, d\theta$, so
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}(1 + x^2)} = \frac{\cos\theta\, d\theta}{(1 + \sin^2\theta)\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}} = \frac{d\theta}{1 + \sin^2\theta}.$$
Now use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html).